# Deprecated createCriteria alternative

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm working on an hibernate application. It look like I was working on hibernate version older than the new 5.2.

And after my maven update I found my query all deprecated... :-(

Before I had :

```
public static <T> List<T> getOnly(Class<T> typeClass, String column, String value) throws DatabaseException {

    return getSession().createCriteria(typeClass).add(Restrictions.eq(column, value)).list();

}
```

It was very simple and clear...

Now I have :

```
public static <T> List<T> getOnly(Class<T> typeClass, String column, String value) throws DatabaseException {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = getSession().getCriteriaBuilder();

     CriteriaQuery<T> query = cb.createQuery(typeClass);
     Root<T> root = query.from(typeClass);
     Path<Set<String>> nicknames = root.get(column);
     query.select(root).where(cb.isMember(value, nicknames));

     return getSession().createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

It not look so simple...

**Anyway, is it correct ? And are there any shorter solution, more "sexy" ??**

NB : I need to keep the method Generic !!

Other example :
SELECT * FROM typeClass

Was :

```
public static <T> List<T> getAll(Class<T> typeClass) throws DatabaseException {

    return getSession().createCriteria(typeClass).list();
}
```

Is now :

```
public static <T> List<T> getAll(Class<T> typeClass) throws DatabaseException {

    CriteriaQuery<T> query = getSession().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(typeClass);

    return getSession().createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```